# Conclave does not start in release mode after passing -PenclaveMode=release

Tags: corda, sgx, enclave, conclave

I am trying to start Conclave in release mode, followed instructions as below :

1. // Firstly, built the signing material:

   `./gradlew prepareForSigning -PenclaveMode=release`
2. // Generated a signature from the signing material. The password for the sample external key is '12345'

   `openssl dgst -sha256 -out signing/signature.bin -sign signing/external_signing_private.pem -keyform PEM enclave/build/enclave/Release/signing_material.bin`
3. // Finally built the signed enclave:

   `./gradlew build -PenclaveMode="release" -x test`
4. `./gradlew host:installDist`
5. `cd host/build/install`
6. `./host/bin/host`

After invoking request from client , the attestation still prints:

> Mode: SIMULATION

Is there any flag/step being missed ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `-PenclaveMode=release` when building the `host:installDist` target otherwise it will build the default Simulation version and package that, even if you previously built the release enclave.

Just run this command and it will use the release enclave instead:

```
./gradlew host:installDist -PenclaveMode=release
```